# Text padding circular progressbar

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am using a circular progressbar, source from [here](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress)

I am having some issues with the padding of the **bottomtext**, as you can see in provided screenhot it is not diplayed complete but cut in half.

I looked throught the sourcecode but could not find any **padding option for the bottom text**, is somebody able to help?

[image]

The .xml file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_verbr"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/linverbr2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.ArcProgress
                android:id="@+id/arc_progress"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:background="#E8EBED"
                custom:arc_progress="58"
                custom:arc_bottom_text="VERBRUIK"/>

            <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.ArcProgress
                android:id="@+id/arc_progress2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:background="#E8EBED"
                custom:arc_progress="55"
                custom:arc_bottom_text="DATA"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Have you tried running it in real device ? It only shows like this in preview not in real device.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna, Yeah just tried on a nexus 9, same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Try adding `android:padding="10dp"` to LinearLayout with id of linverbr2. And please be quick, I am about to leave for 2 days.

Comment: @Simon issue with Library code see :https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress/issues/7 you need to modify library Class  ArcProgress  in onDraw method if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(getBottomText())) { // in side this  }

Comment: Done, same issue. I think I am gonna ad some textviews manually.

Comment: I see @Suhas B 2. Thx but never modified a library Uuuum.

Answer (score 0):

use this code in Xml file without libs

```
 <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
                    android:id="@+id/arc_progress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:progress="55"
                    app:indicatorColor="#1EFF43"

                    app:indicatorSize="170dp"
                    android:layout_margin="12sp"

                    app:trackColor="#1D2525"
                    app:trackCornerRadius="20dp"
                    app:trackThickness="20dp" />
```